# Remove unwanted key on nested unique keys MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have this kind of mongodb document example

```
"data": {
  "2023-02-01": {
    "123": {
      "price": 100,
    },
    "234": {
      "price": 100,
    },
  },
  "2023-02-02": {
    "123": {
      "price": 100,
    },
    "234": {
      "price": 100,
    },
  },
  "2023-02-03": {
    "123": {
      "price": 100,
    },
    "234": {
      "price": 100,
    },
  },
}
```

I have list of mapped ID on my aystem, it should be like

```
ids = [123]
```

I want to remove the key that not in the list (ids) from the document, started from a specific date (today/"2023-02-02"), the date always updated and so the ID, my expected result is

```
"data": {
  "2023-02-01": {
    "123": {
      "price": 100,
    },
    "234": {
      "price": 100,
    },
  },
  "2023-02-02": {
    "123": {
      "price": 100,
    },
  },
  "2023-02-03": {
    "123": {
      "price": 100,
    },
  },
}
```

Could I achieve that on MongoDB aggregation? I'm using pymongo

Comment: Using dynamic values as field name is considered as anti-pattern and introduces unnecessary complexity to queries. And you should avoid highly nesting unless you have very appealing reason to do. You should consider a schema like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/agLi65rvykl)

Comment: Yeah, I thought it better to use that kind of schema, thanks for your suggestion. If I have a document with that schema, do you have another idea to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the discussion in comments, if refactoring the schema is an option, you can achieve what you need in very simple query.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "date": {
    $gte: ISODate("2023-02-02")
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      value: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$value",
          as: "v",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$v.key",
              [
                "123"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QBUebBvgWJw)

---

The schema I am proposing:

```json
[
  {
    "date": ISODate("2023-02-01"),
    "value": [
      {
        "key": "123",
        "price": 100
      },
      {
        "key": "234",
        "price": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2023-02-02"),
    "value": [
      {
        "key": "123",
        "price": 100
      },
      {
        "key": "234",
        "price": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate("2023-02-03"),
    "value": [
      {
        "key": "123",
        "price": 100
      },
      {
        "key": "234",
        "price": 100
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can see there is a few things:

1. avoided using dynamic value as field name
2. formatted date as proper date objects
3. avoided highly nesting arrays/objects